# ASP.NET: Menu make parent items non-hyperlinks?

Tags: asp.net, menu, web.sitemap, flyout, aspmenu-control

I have an asp:Menu control driven by a web.sitemap file.

For example, the menu is like:

```
Fruit
- Apple
- Orange
- Strawberry

Color
- Blue
- Red
- Yellow
```

In the sitemap, the specific fruits are children of the "Fruit" siteMapNode (likewise for the colors) The menu is setup as dynamic so Fruit and Color are static and the specific fruits and colors show up in the popup/flyout menu.  The parent items are just for categorization purposes; there's no "Fruit" page.

How do I make it so "Fruit" and "Color" are NOT links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding an event handler to handle this.  It's not really ideal but it does the job.

```
<asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource" 
OnMenuItemDataBound="MyMenu_MenuItemDataBound">
```

...

```
protected void MyMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode node = (SiteMapNode)e.Item.DataItem;
    if (node.ChildNodes.Count != 0)
    {
        e.Item.Selectable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: but it still rendered as an <a> tag, which is i think accessibility problem, Can we convert that <a> to <span> if it is not select able?

Answer (score 0):

```
<siteMapNode url="" title="Fruit"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Apple.aspx" title="Apple"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Orange.aspx" title="Orange"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Strawberry.aspx" title="Strawberry"/>
</siteMapNode>
```

Like wise with Colors

Comment: I already tried this, but when I do this the whole Fruit menu disappears.

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove the "url" from siteMapNode, like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Fruit"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Apple.aspx" title="Apple"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Orange.aspx" title="Orange"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Strawberry.aspx" title="Strawberry"/>
</siteMapNode>
```